# Reading GeoPackage file with GeoTools: Error on missing gpkg_contents database

Tags: geotools, geopackage

I am trying to read a [GeoPackage](https://www.geopackage.org/) file using [GeoTools](https://geotools.org/) with:

```
GeoPackage gp = new GeoPackage(new File("myFile.gpkg"));
FeatureEntry fe = gp.features().get(0);
SimpleFeatureReader fr = gp.reader(fe, filter, new DefaultTransaction());

while(fr.hasNext()) {
    SimpleFeature sf = fr.next();
    // Do things...
}
fr.close();
gp.close();
```

I get the following error:

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table:
>   gpkg_contents)

which I have no clue how to handle. The input file was produced from [QGIS](https://qgis.org/).
Is there something to take care of concerning this `gpkg_contents` database?

Comment: how was the file created in QGis?

Comment: with export > save Features as and keeping the default options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to access a GeoPackage (or any other data type) in GeoTools is to use the `DataStore` and `DataStoreFinder` classes, so something like:

```
DataStore store;
String filename = "mypackage.gpkg";
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DBTYPE.key, "geopkg");
map.put(GeoPkgDataStoreFactory.DATABASE.key, filename);
try {
  store = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(map);
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
String[] names = store.getTypeNames();

for (String name : names) {
  System.out.println(name);

  SimpleFeatureCollection features = store.getFeatureSource(name).getFeatures();


  try (SimpleFeatureIterator itr = features.features()){

    int count = 0;
    while (itr.hasNext() && count < 10) {
      SimpleFeature f = itr.next();
      System.out.println(f);
      count++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ian for your answer. I tried to test it, however the reader object is not defined. I tried with 'SimpleFeatureCollection features = store.getFeatureSource(name).getFeatures();' but it raised NullPointerException.

Comment: Sorry, I was simplifying on the fly from some more complex code - store.getFeatureSource(name).getFeatures() should work

Comment: I've just tested on a local gpkg created from QGis 3.10 and it works fine. Can you add a link to the file or more details if it continues not to work for you

Comment: OK: It is working now ! Many thanks for your help.